# Is there any tool to convert JSON object to SQLAlchemy model?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm looking for a way to convert list of JSON object into an approximate SQLAlchemy model. Is there any implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did in one of my projects to convert json input from an http request to an `sqlalchemy` model dynamically:

```
if request.method == "POST" or request.method == "PUT":
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    print("data:", data)
    try:
        TableClass = models.get_class_by_tablename(table_name)
        if TableClass == None: raise Exception("Table not found: %s" % table_name)
        if request.method == "POST": #insert data
            object = TableClass(**data)
            dbsession.add(object)
            dbsession.commit()
        else: #update data
            object = dbsession.query(TableClass).filter_by(**{"id":id}).first()
            if object == None: raise Exception("No data found.")
            #object.update(**data)
            for key in data.keys():
                setattr(object, key, data[key])
            #dbsession.add(object)
            dbsession.commit()
        return jsonify({
            "status": "success",
            "id": object.id,
            })
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({
            "status": "error",
            "error": str(e),
            })
```

`data` is the variable that gets converted from json input to the usual python dictionary. Then `**data` is passed as argument for the instance creation of sqlalchemy table class.